# Meteor - how using client bundle to deploy client and server on separate machines

Tags: angular, meteor, ionic-framework, deployment, galaxy

Anybody had any success deploying an ionic or angular application on a different server other than where meteor api is being served

Attempting to deploy ionic-meteor tutorial --  api on galaxy and client on my local server.

Does anybody know of any documentation that helps with this.

**My issue is**: error can't load module 'api/collections' on client side

Error is located in chats.ts in an import

```
import { Chats, Messages, Users, Pictures } from 'api/collections';
```

client webpack config alias is pointing to galaxy .

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json'],
    modules: [path.resolve('node_modules')],
    alias: {
      'api': path.resolve(__dirname, 'https://whatsappsc.eu.meteorapp.com/server') **Does webpack allow this?**
    }
    }
```

server deploy directory structure:
api --> server --> collections